# `react` <div id="root"/> change `div` tag

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, markup

I am currently working on html markup in `react` environment.
What I'm curious about is, my code looks like this.

```
<body>
 <div id="root">
    <div>
      <Header>
      <Section>
      <Footer>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

It is impossible to have header and section inside a div tag.
So I changed `body id="root"` but it gives me an error.

Is there no way to change `div id="root"` `div` to `body` ?

`index.tsx`

```
ReactDOM.render(
 
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,

  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "It is impossible to have header and section inside a div tag."? There's nothing technically impossible about it.

Comment: @AKX It's technically possible, but looking at the html standard it's wrong.

Comment: `Header` and `Section` are React components, not semantic HTML tags, so what you say is impossible is unclear in this context.

Comment: @DrewReese So there is no way? If you look at the homepage made in the react environment, it is not visible in the `<div id="root"/>` Chrome developer tools.

Comment: No way for what? I'm not sure I follow that comment. I view the React apps I work on in the browser dev tools all day long.

Comment: @DrewReese 
Then, if you deploy as a file built with webpack, it won't be hidden, right?As you can see, the ‘react official guideline page’ is also made of divs.

Comment: @skksks The MDN says permissible parents for `<header>` are "Any element that accepts flow content. Note that a <header> element must not be a descendant of an <address>, <footer> or another <header> element." and "Any element that accepts flow content. Note that a <section> element must not be a descendant of an <address> element." for `<section>`. `<div>` accepts flow content.

Answer (score 2):

You can render your React app into `document.body`, but there is an increased risk of collisions with other code which might manipulate that element. See this GitHub issue: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1568

Regarding nested elements: you can use those elements inside a `<div>`, but make sure to close them:

```html
<div>
  <header></header>
  <section></section>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```